# fetching data from model and want to show only 2/3 data per page and through command link want to go next page and show another data

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, security, controller

I have few data in sobject model. i want to fetch those data and show only 2/3 data per page and there is below one command link is there through I want to go to next page and show another data. how it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

### Controller

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController pageController { get; set; }
```

// ... in constructor, or elsewhere
// Change query as necessary. Include needed fields and filters.

```
pageController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Name,Phone,Fax FROM Account]);
```

### Page

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandLink disabled="{!not pageController.hasPrevious}" action="{!pageController.first}" value="First"/>
            <apex:commandLink disabled="{!not pageController.hasPrevious}" action="{!pageController.previous}" value="Previous"/>
            {!pageController.pageNumber}
            <apex:commandLink disabled="{!not pageController.hasNext}" action="{!pageController.next}" value="Next"/>
            <apex:commandLink disabled="{!not pageController.hasNext}" action="{!pageController.last}" value="Last"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pageController.records}" var="record">
           <apex:column value="{!record['name']}" headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!record['phone']}" headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Phone.Label}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!record['fax']}" headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Fax.Label}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Note: I'm doing this mostly from memory, so exact syntax may differ. This is meant to be an example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this very easily by the creating wizard.

how to create wizard

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm